# How to covert each password into their SHA256 hashes using a simple tool

Tags: hashing

Is there a tool to convert each password in a text file into sha256 hash without writing any program? I want to convert each password in "rockyou" password file into their SHA256 form line by line. Do you know any tool for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CGHQ's [Cyberchef GUI](https://cyberchef.org/) online.

If you know the linux command line, this command can help you:

```
touch hashes.txt; n=$(wc -l rockyou.txt | awk '{print $1}'); for ((i=1;i<=$n;i++)); do cut -d$'\n' -f$i rockyou.txt | openssl sha256 | awk '{print $2}' >> hashes.txt;done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a list of passwords into a list of hashes easily enough:

```
while read -r password; do printf "%s" "$password" | sha256sum | cut -c 1-64; done < rockyou.txt
```

However, this looks like you are storing passwords as hashes, and want to see if any of them match one in the rockyou list. **Passwords must not be stored that way**. Passwords shall be stored salted, precisely so that an attacker cannot make a password guess and see if that is the password of *any* of the users, but to bruteforce each of the entries individually.